# twitter bootstrap in windows modern app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, windows, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm implementing a simple cross-platform app. I need at least win8 and Android compatibility. I've decided to use PhoneGap and twitter bootstrap for that.

When I try to implement a fluid UI using bootstrap grid, it fails to render correctly in win8. For ex, when I try the following sample grid html:

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
```

I get correct layout in browser, but in win8 modern app emulator all the columns  are always stretched to entire screen. No matter how wide the screen is.

Is there a way to fix that? Or bootstrap isn't compatible with win8? What could be the alternative then? I need something that I can reuse across win8 and mobile html5 apps.

Comment: Before you proceed, i guess you know that win8 uses IE10 and win8.1 uses IE11 as the in app browser for cordova apps. Secondly, appending dynamic HTML in win 8 apps is not possible until you add a shim for that.

Comment: I might be fine actually due to the app simplicity. :) but since you mentioned, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I usually test all my windows 8 mobile specific stuff in IE10. If it works in there, it's ought to work in the mobile too..

Comment: this approach doesn't work for me :) sample html above works in ie10 emulator but doesn't work in windows app emulator.

Answer (score 0):

on android it looks fine as you expected?

I'm asking because i don't know what  you expect, using col-md-* will stretch when the screen resolution is less than 992 px

here the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options
maybe you wanted to use col-sm-* ?

something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying on windows desktop emulator, which has bigger resolution. Sorry for confusion, I also tried example mixing md and sm. I'll double check.